# Method of superposition and Linear PDE.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

> Consider the steady state two dimensional heat equation $$\nabla^2\theta=0$$
>
> under the boundary condition
>
> $\theta(0,y)=0$
> $\theta(L,y)=0$
> $\theta(x,0)=\phi(x)-T_0$
> $\theta(x,L)=f(x)-T_0$

If I assume my $\theta=\theta_1+\theta_2$ then my equations becomes $$\nabla^2\theta_1+\nabla^2\theta_2=0$$

Then how can we come to the conclusion that

$\nabla^2\theta_1=0$

$\theta_1(0,y)=0$
$\theta_1(L,y)=0$
$\theta_1(x,0)=\phi(x)-T_0$
$\theta_1(x,L)=0$

---

$\nabla^2\theta_2=0$

$\theta_2(0,y)=0$
$\theta_2(L,y)=0$
$\theta_2(x,0)=0$
$\theta_2(x,L)=f(x)-T_0$

The motivation behind this is the fact that now I can solve the two independent problem with method of separation of variables.

I am assuming it has to do something with the linearity of the equation but I  am not able to **rigorously** understand how can we just "divide" boundary condition as well as the governing equation.

Comment: What are your definitions of ${\theta}_1$ and ${\theta}_2$?

Comment: $\theta_1=\theta_1(x,y)$ and $\theta_2=\theta_2(x,y)$ are arbitrary function satisfying the above two independent problems.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if I understand your question. Anyway, it seems to me that you are reasoning backwards. In other words, you should simply solve the two problems for $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, and observe that $\theta = \theta_1+\theta_2$ is a solution of the first problem. This is a consequence of the linearity of the PDE, as you can easily check.

The decomposition is not unique, since you could also split the boundary conditions between $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ in different ways.

Comment: That makes more sense than the question as posed.